# How to receive and show LOB.com postcard cURL/API requests in C# with webRequest Class

Tags: c#, curl, httpclient, lob

I am trying to get postcard information from LOB.com account using CURL.

lob.com they are providing:

```
curl https://api.lob.com/v1/postcards/psc_5c002b86ce47537a \
  -u test_0dc8d51e0acffcb1880e0f19c79b2f5b0cc:
```

How can I get the json response using this CURL?

I've used

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://api.lob.com/v1/postcards/psc_95d1eafeb5b9a766");

httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

httpWebRequest.Accept = "*/*";

httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";

httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "test_48d2bbf75c2edc75155c401d119bfae5526:");

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
 gta_allCustomersResponse answer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < gta_allCustomersResponse > (streamReader.ReadToEnd());
 return answer;
```

Above code showing 422 (Unprocessable entity) or 400 (Bad request) error if I run this code.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: C# I guess... based on the title too.

Comment: Is this answer resolved your issue?

Comment: before i got ur answer i got what i expected ... that too the same like ur answer.. your answer is also very useful.. thanks @div

Comment: @saravanan049: And where did you get it from? c-sharp corner? :)

Comment: no.. somewhere here in stackoverflow..StringBuilder postdata = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in zDicPageData)
                {
                    postdata.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", item.Key, item.Value);
                }
                using (Stream writeStream = zHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
                    byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postdata.ToString());
                    writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }

Comment: like the above ... i used to convert dictionary data to HTTPRequest... more or less same like ur code... but.. very much thanks for ur valuable answer..

Comment: @saravanan049: Glad to know that your issue has been resolved and I could help you anyway. Do not forgot to up-vote and accept the answer!!  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) to send simple HTTP requests to Lob.

Or you can make it using HttpClient:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string API_KEY = "YourApiKey";

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var authHeaderBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(API_KEY + ":");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(authHeaderBytes));

    var requestPayload = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "name", "John Doe" },
        { "address_line1", "123 Main St" },
        { "address_city", "San Francisco" },
        { "address_state", "CA" },
        { "address_zip", "94107" },
        { "address_country", "US" }
    };

    var encodedRequestForm = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestPayload);
    var APIResponse = httpClient.PostAsync("https://api.lob.com/v1/addresses", encodedRequestForm).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    var addressString = APIResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    System.Console.WriteLine(addressString);
}
```

This example is for an address, you can develop same for postcards, just review the curl request or Java request from the documentation and code accordingly.

Hope this helps!